# Attempt to assign property "household_head_id" on null

Tags: laravel

When I tried to update the household and hit update button, it says Attempt to assign property "household_head_id" on null.

**controller**:

```
public function update(Request $request, string $id)
{
    $household = HouseholdHead::find($id);

    $household->name = $request->name;
    $household->purok_id = $request->purok;
    $household->env_hazard_id = $request->hazards;
    $household->number_of_adults = $request->adults;
    $household->save();

    $categories = [ 'sdoh_One', 'sdoh_Two', 'sdoh_Three', 'sdoh_Four' ];


    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $sdohCategory = SDOHCategoryHousehold::find($id);
        $sdohCategory->household_head_id = $household->id;
        $sdohCategory->sdoh_category_id = $request->get($category);
        $sdohCategory->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin.household.index')->with('success', 'Household Head Updated Successfully!');


}
```

Comment: You can add findOrFail to the `HouseholdHead::find($id)`, because your `find` returned `null`.

Comment: Hey, basic debugging needed here. You are using `find`, it returns `null` as the other user mentioned, you have to use `findOrFail` if you are not accounting on getting `null` as a result...

Answer (score 0):

Your **find()** method is returning null. Modify your code according like below for debugging and view what you are getting actually from database. Use dump() for that. After that, modify your code according to need

```
public function update(Request $request, string $id)
{
    $household = HouseholdHead::find($id);

    $household->name = $request->name;
    $household->purok_id = $request->purok;
    $household->env_hazard_id = $request->hazards;
    $household->number_of_adults = $request->adults;
    $household->save();

    $categories = [ 'sdoh_One', 'sdoh_Two', 'sdoh_Three', 'sdoh_Four' ];


    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $sdohCategory = SDOHCategoryHousehold::find($id);
        dump($sdohCategory );
        //$sdohCategory->household_head_id = $household->id;
        //$sdohCategory->sdoh_category_id = $request->get($category);
        //$sdohCategory->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin.household.index')->with('success', 'Household Head Updated Successfully!');


}
```

Comment: I tried the dump function and it returns null, why is that.

Comment: maybe id missmatch in database or not exist. check it