# select old value in dropdown for updating

Tags: laravel

I want to update the household information, but an error shows the old value in the dropdown. The views refused to show the old value in the dropdown.

edit controller:

```
  public function edit(string $id)
{
    $household = HouseholdHead::find($id);
    $puroks = Purok::all();
    $env_hazards = EnvHazard::all();
    $categories = SDOHCategory::all();

    $sdoh_one = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'SDOH 1')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $sdoh_two = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'SDOH 2')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $sdoh_three = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'SDOH 3')->first()->sdoh_category;
    $sdoh_four = SDOH::where('sdoh', 'SDOH 4')->first()->sdoh_category;

    return view('household_edit', compact('puroks', 'categories', 'env_hazards', 'sdoh_one', 'sdoh_two','sdoh_three', 'sdoh_four', 'household'));


}
```

update controller:

```
 public function update(Request $request, string $id)
{
    $household = HouseholdHead::find($id);

    $household->name = $request->name;
    $household->purok_id = $request->purok;
    $household->env_hazard_id = $request->hazards;
    $household->number_of_adults = $request->adults;
    $household->save();

    $categories = [ 'sdoh_One', 'sdoh_Two', 'sdoh_Three', 'sdoh_Four' ];

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $sdohCategory = new SDOHCategoryHousehold();
        $sdohCategory->household_head_id = $household->id;
        $sdohCategory->sdoh_category_id = $request->get($category);
        $sdohCategory->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin.household.index')->with('success', 'Household Head Updated Successfully!');


}
```

this is **views**:

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="sdoh_One" id="sdoh_One" required>
                            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select SDOH 1</option>

                            @foreach($sdoh_one as $sdoh_ones)
                                <option value="{{ $sdoh_ones->id}}" @if($sdoh_ones->sdoh_One  == $sdoh_ones->id) selected @endif>{{ $sdoh_ones->category }}</option>

                            @endforeach



                        </select>
                        <label for="floatingSelect"> SDOH 1</label>
                      </div>
```

**views**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxVR6.png)

Comment: don't open more questions. stick with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77599009/attempt-to-assign-property-household-head-id-on-null) and update..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attempt to assign property "household\_head\_id" on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77599009/attempt-to-assign-property-household-head-id-on-null)